# how do you escape shebang line when generating a shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am generating a shell script from within a script and it needs root permissions so I use

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'Hello There!' > '/var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.3.8'"
```

I get an error if I try to output the shebang line and I not sure how to escape it -- like i do with other variables.

```
sudo bash -c "echo '#!/bin/bash

version=\"5.3.8\"
export PHPRC=/etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-\${version}/lib/php.ini
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
exec /etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-\${version}/bin/php-cgi' > '/var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.3.8'"
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is looking for a command beginning with `'` in your bash_history. You should have the '!' unquoted and escape it with a backslash. You may as well take the `#` out of quotes and escape it too, since a `\` is shorter than two quotes.

```
sudo bash -c "echo \#\!'/bin/bash

version=\"5.3.8\"
export PHPRC=/etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-\${version}/lib/php.ini
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
exec /etc/php/phpfarm/inst/php-\${version}/bin/php-cgi' > '/var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.3.8'"
```

Comment: I think the first single quote should be right after the "echo ".

Comment: @gpojd Nope, it's in the right place. That's why I escaped the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` is probably trying to replace with something in your history. Try `...'#\!/bin/bash...`.

Comment: or do this first `set +o histexpand`